# How to merge rows of duplicate column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

Suppose, I have text file looks like the following.

```
name1 2 3 4
name2 5 6 7
name1 4 5 3 
name3 4 5 6
name4 5 6 7
name3 4 5 7
name2 3 5 7
name7 1 2 3
name7 2 3 4
name7 4 5 6
name7 5 6 7
```

I want to see the first column. If It contains duplicate values then I want to merge those rows(by their mean values). But I don't want to merge rows for a specific values for example `name7`. The result would be like the following one of the previous example.

```
name1 3 4 3.5 
name2 4 5.5 7
name3 4 5 6.5
name4 5 6 7
name7 1 2 3
name7 2 3 4
name7 4 5 6
name7 5 6 7
```

How can I do that in python?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.groupby(0).mean().reset_index()` replace 0 with the name of the first column

Comment: @anky_91, I update my question.

Comment: first do `m=df[0].eq('name7')` then `pd.concat([df[~m].groupby(0).mean().reset_index(),df[m]],ignore_index=True)`